# Django adding additional field on query set result

Tags: python, django, api

i have these code on my Django

```
    def get(self, request):
        movie = Movie.objects.all().order_by('name').first()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movie)
        serializer_data = serializer.data
        return Response(serializer_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and it returns this data

```
{
    {
      "description": "Haunted House Near You",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Scary Night",
    },
    {
      "description": "Netflix and Chill",
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Movie Night",
    },
}
```

i want to add custom field , called 'alias' like this

```
{
    {
      "description": "Haunted House Near You",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Scary Night",
      "alias": "SN"
    },
    {
      "description": "Netflix and Chill",
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Movie Night",
      "alias": "MN"
    },
}
```

My Question is, how do i add the custom field using ORM on Django?

Comment: if you are getting JSON format in `serializer_data` then iterate and add a field in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add a field based on your object with SerializerMethodField.
By default, it looks for get_NameOfField method inside your serializer. Note that this is a read only field which i believe is what you're looking for.

Here is an example which gives the first letter of each word of your object's name.

```py
# serializers.py

class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    alias = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        # class meta stuff

    def get_alias(self, obj):
        return "".join([s[0] for s in obj.name.split()])
```

This is much more efficient than trying to use an additional query in your view.

Hope that helped.